# Suppose A be a matrix with Diagonal entries are $\alpha+1$ then $\alpha $ is?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $10\times 10$ order matrix such that $a_{ij}$=$1$ for $i\neq j$ and$ a_{ii}=\alpha+1$ for $\alpha\ge 0$.Let $ \lambda$  and  $\mu $ be largest and smallest eigenvalues of $A$. If$\lambda+\mu=24$ then $\alpha=?$                           here is my attempt -- according to the question diagonal elements are $\alpha+1$ and remaining entries are 1 then as sum of eigen value =sum of diagonal $10\alpha+10$=$\lambda+\mu+\sum_{i=2}^9\lambda_i $ suppose $\lambda_1=\mu$ and $\lambda_{10}=\lambda$ then $10\alpha$=$14+\sum_{i=2}^9\lambda_i $ as $\lambda+\mu=24$ but how can I find $\alpha$, is my process is correct? If not then what is the correct process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B$ be the $10\times10$ matrix such that all entries are equal to $1$. Then $B$ has $2$ eigenvalues: $10$ (multiplicity $1$) and $0$ (multiplicity $9$). Therefore, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $10+\alpha$ and $\alpha$, because if $P(\lambda)$ is characteristic polynomial of $B$, then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $P(\lambda-\alpha)$. So, the largest eigenvalue is $10+\alpha$ and the smallest one is $\alpha$. Since their sum is $10+2a=24$, $\alpha=7$.

Comment: Can you please explain why the eigenvalues of $A+xI$ are $\lambda_i+x$ where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: @gt6989b I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: Sir I understand, but a little doubt ,for all entries equal to 1 largest and smallest eigenvalues are 10 and 0 .similarly for $\alpha+1$ it is $\alpha+10$ if $a_{ii}=\alpha $ then what is the required solution

Comment: @mSourav I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: If diagonal entries are $\alpha$ not $\alpha+1$ then what is the solution

Comment: @mSourav You do as I did, but with $\alpha-1$ instead of $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you sir thank you very much all of my doubts are cleared